# Typescript import module npm

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, module

I need to create a method called rollDice which uses the 'random' library to generate and return a random integer between 1 and 6. This is the code I have so far:

```
import random from 'random'

function rollDice(min:number, max:number) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}
 
let result = rollDice(1,6)
console.log(result)
```

I don't know how to call the 'random'
thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [usage instructions](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/random#usage) for that module:

```
int value = random.int((min = 1), (max = 6));
```

This returns a uniformly distributed integer in the 1 (inclusive) to 6 (inclusive) range.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!! My mind wasn't focusing... I guess I need to sleep 8 hours a day, thanks again!